# How to get different user in firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app, and part of the functionality of the app is an admin being able to sign in and reset other users' passwords. How do I get a user other than the one currently signed in?

```
resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newPass = resetForm['reset-password'].value;
        let firebaseUser = auth.user(docId);
        console.log(firebaseUser);
    });
```

I understand that that code won't actually reset any password, I just wrote that to see if I could get a user other than the one already signed in. I ran it, but instead of seeing the User UID in the console I saw this:

> Uncaught TypeError: auth.user is not a function

Edit:
I have created a cloud function. Here is the code of my index.js file:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("/removed-for-privacy.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://troop-30-elections-web-app.firebaseio.com"
});
    exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((docId,newPass) => {
        console.log("step 2");
        admin.auth().updateUser(docId, {
            password: newPass,
        }).then(() => {
            const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-reset');
              M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
              resetForm.reset();
        });
    });
```

Here is the code that runs when the button is pressed:

```
resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        console.log("Step 1");
        e.preventDefault();
        let newPass = resetForm['reset-password'].value;
        const resetPasswordFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('resetPassword');
        resetPasswordFunction(docId,newPass);
        console.log("Step 1.5");
    });
```

When I open the console, there are no error messages. I see step 1 and step 1.5. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to identify an application administrator in Firebase Authentication. You will have to build your own infrastructure for this.

Typically this means:

1. In a trusted environment (like a server you control, or Cloud Function) you [use the Admin SDK to change their password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user).
2. You then wrap that code into a custom API, that you expose to your application.
3. You call the API from your application, passing along the ID token of the signed in user.
4. In the API you [verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and make sure the caller is authorized for the operation.

You are completely on your own here though, as you can't use Firebase's built in password reset mechanism. That is only available to the signed-in user on the client, to prevent it being abused to spam users.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and let you know what happens.

Comment: I created a cloud function to reset the password. I made an edit to my post with the new code.

Comment: You asked how to do administrative actions in a client app that uses Firebase, I explained why that isn't possible, and how to implement the use-case. If my answer made sense, and you're having trouble implementing one of the steps, it's a good moment to accept this answer, and post a new question so that others can help with that too. This seems more related to Callable Cloud Functions than to Authentication.